# filter list of dictionaries with varying key and values

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary

I need a function that filters a list of dictionaries with key-value pairs without hardcoding the key-value filter. The filter parameter may have either one key-value filter or n many key-value filters.

```
data = [
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "city" : "Paris", "population": 123},
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "city" : "Bordeaux", "population": 234},
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"Spain", "city" : "Barcelona", "population": 345},
    {"continent": "North America", "country":"USA", "city" : "New York", "population": 456},
    {"continent": "Asia", "country":"Japan", "city" : "Tokyo", "population": 456},
]
```

Is there a more efficient/more pythonic way of writing the function than what I have:

```
def filter_data(data, **kwargs):
    lookup = list(data)
    for k,  v in kwargs.items():
            result = [d for d in lookup if d[k] in v]
            lookup=result
            
    return result

print(filter_data(data, **{"continent" : ["North America", "Asia"]}))

>> [{'continent': 'North America', 'country': 'USA', 'city': 'New York', 'population': 456},
{'continent': 'Asia', 'country': 'Japan', 'city': 'Tokyo', 'population': 456}]


print(filter_data(data, **{"continent" : "Europe", "country" : "France"}))

>>[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}, 
{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Bordeaux', 'population': 234}]
```

Answer (score 0):

What about this one?

```py
def filter_data(data, **kwargs):
    return [
        d for d in data
        if all(d[k] in v for k, v in kwargs.items())
    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

The cleanest way to do this, would likely be the `filter` function, which filters an iterable based on a function argument.

**Note:** `filter` is a built-in function, you don't need to import anything to use it

To avoid conflicts between the `data` argument and the actual list of data, I've renamed the list to `dta` in my examples.

## Basic usage of `filter()`

```py
dta = [
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "city" : "Paris", "population": 123},
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"France", "city" : "Bordeaux", "population": 234},
    {"continent": "Europe", "country":"Spain", "city" : "Barcelona", "population": 345},
    {"continent": "North America", "country":"USA", "city" : "New York", "population": 456},
    {"continent": "Asia", "country":"Japan", "city" : "Tokyo", "population": 456},
]

american = filter(lambda d: d['continent'] == 'North America', dta)

print(list(american))
# [{'continent': 'North America', 'country': 'USA', 'city': 'New York', 'population': 456}]
```

## A filtering generator function (matches against **ANY** kwarg)

This could be used dynamically within a small generator function, to achieve the same effect as your original more complex example:

```py
def filter_data(data, **kwargs):
    data, kwargs = list(data), dict(kwargs)
    # A data item is returned if it matches ANY of the kwargs
    for k, v in kwargs.items():
        yield from list(filter(lambda d: d[k] == v, data))
```

Since the function is a generator, it needs to either be iterated over using a `for` loop (`for x in filter_data(data, country='France')`), or using `list` which will iterate over the entire generator: `list(filter_data(data, country='France')`

```py
>>> list(filter_data(dta, country='France'))
[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}, 
{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Bordeaux', 'population': 234}]
```

This `filter_data` function acts as an `OR` filter with the kwargs, meaning if you supply `country='France'` and `city='New York'`, you get both `France` country results, and `New York` city results combined.

```
>>> list(filter_data(dta, country='France', city='New York'))
[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123},
 {'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Bordeaux', 'population': 234}, 
 {'continent': 'North America', 'country': 'USA', 'city': 'New York', 'population': 456}]
```

## A filtering generator function (matches against **ALL** kwargs)

You weren't clear whether you required the filters to filter individually (`OR`), or for the filters to be combined (`AND`) - so here's an alternative example that matches data against all kwargs.

The function can be tweaked using the `all` built-in function in order to apply the filters in an `AND` layout.

The `all` function takes an iterable (e.g. a list) of boolean values, and returns `True` only if every value in the iterable is truthy.

```py
def filter_data_and(data, **kwargs):
    data, kwargs = list(data), dict(kwargs)
    # Each data item is checked against ALL kwargs before matching in the filter
    matches = filter(
        lambda d: all([d[k] == v for k, v in kwargs.items()]), 
        data
    )
    yield from list(matches)
```

Now, to demonstrate, this is two calls to `filter_data_and`, the first with simply `country='France'`, and a second with the same country kwarg PLUS `city='Paris'`.

With the first `filter_data` function, the additional kwarg would result in a duplicate match - while with `filter_data_and`, it restricts the results to those which have both `country = France` and `city = Paris`

```py
>>> list(filter_data_and(dta, country='France'))
[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}, 
 {'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Bordeaux', 'population': 234}]

>>> # 'filter_data_and' matches against ALL kwargs, so it only returns the entry
>>> # containing both country 'France' AND city 'Paris'
>>> list(filter_data_and(dta, country='France', city='Paris'))
[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}]

>>> # The original 'filter_data' which acts in an OR fashion, returns duplicates
>>> # if two or more matchers match the same entry:
>>> list(filter_data(dta, country='France', city='Paris'))
[{'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}, 
 {'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Bordeaux', 'population': 234}, 
 {'continent': 'Europe', 'country': 'France', 'city': 'Paris', 'population': 123}]
```